# google play: How can I have different apks distributed to different countries but with same version?

Tags: android, google-play

I have the requirement giving a different app name in some countries. As the app name is declared in the application label in the AndroidManifest.xml, so I need to distributed a different apk for those countris.

How to achive this goal in google play? Can I have the two apks with different app name and the same version uploaded to google play, one distributed to some countries, and the other one to other countries?

Comment: you have 2 options: having different version_code and same package name, or different package names and same version_code.

Comment: ok, I see, thanks. So the two apks with different version can be rolled out at the same time, if they are distributed to different countries?

Comment: yes, sure. just use same package name and different versions. And likely you need to upload lower version first

Answer (score 0):

Please check both the links

1) [Google Developers](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks#Rules)

2) [Google Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7550024?hl=en)

I hope this solves the problem but you have to change the version for that release for sure keeping the package name same as before.

Comment: thanks. seems I need keeps them same package but different version.